# Footer placement

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. The left one is known as #menudiv and the right one is known as #contentdiv. The CSS is presented below:

```
#menudiv{
    width:20%;
    padding:3px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    font-family:ubuntu;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#404040;
}

#contentdiv{
    font-family:verdana;
}

#footer{
    position:relative;
    float:bottom;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Now it visible that I have set menudiv's height to 100%. This is because I don't want contentdiv to spread out and cover the space under menudiv once menudiv's elements have ended.

After writing all the content of contentdiv, I now need to place a footer at the bottom of the page. The issue is that the footer content appears right under contentdiv (because menudiv's height is set to 100%). I want the elements/contents of the footer to spread evenly at the bottom of the page (so that they start from under menudiv).

This is the page structure:

```
<div id="menudiv">
    <img class="titleico" src="images/home.png" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; HOME<br />
    <ul id="menulist">
        <li><a href="yo">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li>Menu item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="contentdiv">
    <!-- several paragraphs go here as seen in the image at bottom -->
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div>Footer item 1</div>
    <div>Footer item 2</div>
    <div>Footer item 3</div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: either your footer is inside your contentdiv or your menudiv pushes it aside

Comment: i think u divided the html in 2 horizontal divs and the footer it's in the content.

Comment: No. The footer is not included within contentdiv. It is another div that comes after contentdiv. But it is being placed under contentdiv because menudiv's height is set to 100%

Comment: Here is an [example with a little bit of flex and calc](http://jsbin.com/hofulahuhi/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @misterManSam: Looks helpful. I'd investigate that approach in some detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: none` and `clear: both` to your footer. Since your footer is not a block level element and the previous elements are floating, the footer is positioned such.

```
footer{
clear: both;
float: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does put the footer at the bottom rightfully, but ... it has jumped ***really really*** down and is looking strange and stupid :S How can I try and get it up slightly?

Comment: There is a **lot** of margin between contentdiv and footer now. Is there any way I can decrease that empty space?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I have suggested an edit with an image. View it. The green box shows where I want it.

Comment: If your inner element of content div, say the paragraph have top and bottom margin this may happen. By default `<p>` tag have margins. You can adjust it such as, `#contentdiv p:last-child{ margin-bottom: 0; }`

This will set the last paragraph in content div to 0. This may solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't work. I even tried with p{margin-bottom:0px;} still no use

:( anyway. I have marked your answer as correct coz you helped a lot :)

Comment: Do you have the page anywhere live in the internet?  If so please add the link or create a Fiddle in https://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: http://daera.net/daera      The problem is with the footer at the end of the page. It appears too down. Also if I add some more content to contentdiv, it breaks the line and new lines get started from the full left margin (under the menudiv)

Answer (score 0):

wrap both your menu and content in a container and put your footer after that. This way the menu will be 100% of the container not the html body. And the container will be whatever height your contentdiv allows.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="menudiv"></div>
    <div id="contentdiv"></div>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: I was very hopeful that this would work (theoretically it solves the problem indeed!) but when I tried it, it doesn't do anything to the output :( Also check out the update (added html)

Answer (score 0):

change your footer style like this

```
<div id="footer" style="clear:both">
<div style="float:left;width:25%">Footer item 1</div>
<div style="float:right;width:25%">Footer item 2</div>
<div style="float:right;width:25%">Footer item 3</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't help much. The footer is already placed in the bottom as Viswalinga has suggested. Now the only problem is that there is a lot of margin between footer and contentdiv which I want to decrase.